# mysql query to laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

can anyone help me to convert this query into laravel 5:

```
SELECT `id`,`mobile_number`,`shortcode`,`chapter_id`,`message`
FROM tbl_votes 
WHERE id in (SELECT MAX(id) from tbl_votes GROUP BY `mobile_number`, position_id)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out. Thanks

```
DB::table('votes')->whereIn('id', function($query){
            $query->select(DB::raw('MAX(id) as id'))
                ->from('votes')
                ->groupBy('mobile_number', 'position_id');
        })->where(array('shortcode'=>$shortcode,'position_id'=>$positionId))->get();
```